# Webpage not loading when using Dash in Python

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a dashboard using Dash module in python, but when I run the below code, nothing pops up.

I manually copied and pasted http://127.0.0.1:8050/ to the web browser, but it says "This site can't be reached"

```
import dash  
import dash_core_components as dcc  
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div('Dash')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This is the error message I got:

```
import dash...
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 
Debugger PIN:
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code to run on my machine. It works fine, and the page loads showing "Dash".

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? I'm using PyCharm and when I click the link in the console it seems to work. Making sure to scroll all the way to the bottom to make sure the link you click is from the last piece of code run. I can't tell you why this would be, but this is what worked for me after facing the same issue.